# Encoded Hex string decoded back to bytes steps?

Tags: python

I'm following the steps on a flag challenge via cryptohack. However when I attempt to decode the hex string back into bytes... it says syntaxerror: invalid syntax. Can anyone explain to me what step is incorrect or is there something I'm missing that wasn't explained on the exercise?

```
Included below is a flag encoded as a hex string. Decode this back into bytes to get the flag.

63727970746f7b596f755f77696c6c5f62655f776f726b696e675f776974685f6865785f737472696e67735f615f6c6f747d
```

It states:

> In Python, the bytes.fromhex() function can be used to convert hex to bytes. The .hex() instance method can be called on byte strings to get the hex representation.
>
> When we encrypt something the resulting ciphertext commonly has bytes
> which are not printable ASCII characters. If we want to share our
> encrypted data, it's common to encode it into something more
> user-friendly and portable across different systems.

Comment: Show the code that is generating the invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

the main thing you had to recognize is that it is a hex text

So

```
texte = "63727970746f7b596f755f77696c6c5f62655f776f726b696e675f776974685f6865785f737472696e67735f615f6c6f747d"
print(bytes.fromhex(texte))
```

Result:

```
crypto{You_will_be_working_with_hex_strings_a_lot}
```

maybe before hacking you should take some tutorials or courses about programming datatypes and datastrues.

Comment: I'm actually enrolled in a Cybersecurity intro program at a state university and learning but was just looking into some extra sites to learn and play around with. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: then you have a bit of way ahead :D